# How do I upgrade juju from a development version to a release?

Tags: upgrade, juju

```
$ juju version
1.22.1-trusty-amd64
```

juju status shows all my agents are running version 1.21.3. The help for juju upgrade-juju tells me this is a development version. Is this a supported upgrade path?

I try to upgrade-juju and I get "no upgrades available"

```
$ juju upgrade-juju
no upgrades available
```

I thought maybe I had to run sync-tools, but that does not change anything.

```
$ juju sync-tools
$ juju upgrade-juju
no upgrades available
```

Comment: Which provider are you using?

Comment: This was/is using the maas provider.

Answer (score 2):

The link to this bug may help you:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju-core/+bug/1325040

I think you need:

> juju upgrade-juju --upload-tools

Answer (score 2):

I believe that 1.22.1 is no longer a development version, it is the most recent stable release.

I ran into the opposite of what you are doing in that I needed to upgrade my Juju from 1.22.1 to 1.23 or higher.

You can do this by cloning the git repo and using

```
go get -v -d github.com/juju/juju/...
cd github.com/juju/juju
sudo make install-dependencies
go install -v github.com/juju/juju/...
```

If you are feeling adventurous....

```
go get -v -d github.com/juju/juju/...
git checkout -b 1.21 remote/1.21
go build github.com/juju/juju/...
go install github.com/juju/juju/...
```

Athough the second set of commands, I was missing certain go dependencies. I'm just learning Golang.

Answer (score 2):

Ah... you have alerted us to some out of date documentation.

As of the 1.20 release of Juju, all development versions are tagged with -alpha or -beta.

1.22.1 and 1.21.3 are both fully supported, released versions of Juju.

To migrate an environment from 1.21.3 to 1.22.1, you do the following:

```
juju upgrade-juju
```

That is all.  By default it will look for a version that matches the client and find the tools in the simple streams definition for the cloud you are using.

If you are using your own openstack cloud then you need to make sure that the tools have been sync'ed.